# Auto-expansion problem with array elements containing an '*' (asterisk)

Tags: bash, shell, find, array, brace-expansion

I'm trying to write me a `find` script that should later be able to read a list of directories to be excluded from an external file. Whilst I can accomplish that part myself, it's the annoying array expansion that makes the task difficult.
First, some "preparations" in order to obtain a suitable sample directory tree:

```
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp
$ mkdir excl1_dirx excl2_dirx excl3_dirx
$ touch excl1_dirx/dummy1.txt excl2_dirx/dummy2.txt excl3_dirx/dummy3.txt
$ mkdir excl1_diry excl2_diry excl3_diry
$ touch excl1_diry/dummy4.txt excl2_diry/dummy5.txt excl3_diry/dummy6.txt
$ touch dummy00.txt dummy01.txt
```

If the script works, only `dummy00.txt` and `dummy01.txt` may be shown.

```
#!/bin/bash
excl_d=("excl*_dirx" "excl*_diry")

find_str=" . -type f ! ( "

for ((i=0 ; i<$((${#excl_d[*]})) ; i++)); do
   if [[ $i > 0 ]]; then
     find_str+=" -o "
   fi

  find_str+=" -path \"./${excl_d[i]}/*\""
done

find_str+=" )"

# this is just for debugging
echo "[debug] value of str = find $find_str"

find $find_str
```

First of all: why so (seemingly) complicated in the line before the "`done`"? Well, `bash` sometimes likes to annoy the users by doing things they don't expect. Without those quotes, it will **expand** each array element; e. g. `excl*_dirx` will become `excl1 dirx excl2 dirx excl3 dirx`, which (obviously) breaks the `-path` line! And that although I've used a pair of double quotes per array element, which was actually supposed to prevent bash from doing its expansion mischief!

However, the best is yet to come: the second last line - when the `(` `)` are escaped to `\(` `\)` - will work fine in the shell, but not in a standalone script. Even though it won't throw any errors, the result in the latter implementation will be wrong.

I've tried all kinds of combinations with single and double quotes in the

```
find_str+=" -path \"./${excl_d[i]}/*\""
```

line, but I just can't get it to work even though it looks absolutely perfect when displayed as in the second last line. It seems that `bash` internally treats my escaped quotes `\"` differently from non-escaped ones. Ah, and quotes inside quotes work near everywhere *but* for some reason will get filtered out when using that `+=` operator.

Not only am I looking for an explanation for this behavior but also for a solution how it could be made work in a standalone script. It must really be a stupid mistake I've made. :-/

Comment: [Don't put commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) - they weren't designed to work that way.  What are you *really* trying to do?  Is your end goal to just print a file list or do you plan to do something with that list?

Comment: 1. I did not. I merely put _parameters_ for `find` in a variable but as you can see in the very last line, I'm actually calling `find` natively. -- 2. Yes, I want to get me a file list w/excluding a bunch of directories to find files which are at locations where they don't belong. (e. g. *.mp3 files in a location where I have my office stuff). So it will be the "good" locations which are excluded so my list doesn't get cluttered with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `find_str` is a string, which is then used as a list of strings. [jw013's comment is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49405/auto-expansion-problem-with-array-elements-containing-an-asterisk#comment69103_49405), and do read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You're not putting the whole command in a variable, but the problem arises as soon as you try to stuff multiple words in a string variable.

In Bourne/POSIX shells, this is a necessary evil. But in ksh/bash/zsh, there's a better way: use an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
excl_d=("excl*_dirx" "excl*_diry")
find_str=( . -type f \! \( )
for ((i=0 ; i<$((${#excl_d[*]})) ; i++)); do
   if [[ $i > 0 ]]; then
     find_str+=( -o )
   fi
  find_str+=( -path "./${excl_d[i]}/*" )
done
find_str+=( \) )
find "$find_str[@]}"
```

There's an easier way of expressing such a filter.

```
#!/bin/bash
exclude_patterns=("excl*_dirx" "excl*_diry")
exclude_args=()
while [[ ${#exclude_patterns} -gt 0 ]]; do
  exclude_args+=( -path "./${exclude_patterns[1]}/*" -prune -o )
  shift exclude_patterns
done
find "${exclude_args[@]}" -type f
```

Comment: In one word: FANTASTIC! I would never have been able to pull all that off by myself (yet), because I'm still learning the advanced stuff like functions and arrays (after considering myself safe enough in the basics, which took way longer than I had expected). Thank you very much, your approach looks as if taken from a textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
#!/bin/bash
excl_d=("excl*_dirx" "excl*_diry")

find_str=". "

for ((i=0 ; i<$((${#excl_d[*]})) ; i++)); do
    if [[ $i > 0 ]]; then
    find_str+=" -o "
    fi

    find_str+=" -path \"./\${excl_d[i]}\" -prune "
done

find_str+=" -o -type f -print "

# this is just for debugging
echo "[debug] value of str = find $find_str"

eval "find ${find_str}"
```

The problem here is that when bash executes a line in the script `find ${find_str}` it then executes find with just one argument, i.e. argc argument of main function in find will be equal 2. `eval` in contrast composes the string that then passes tokenizing in bash.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but no, that does _not_ fix the problem. I still get also files in directories that are in my exclusion list. Though those braces can cure a lot, they are no universal remedy either.

Comment: Please see answer to jw013's comment. (2.)) BTW, I _did_ copy-paste the script and tested it, and there were no errors.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it still does not work. Same as before: there are files shown which are inside directories in my exclusion list. Ahem, can you please try to use your updated script on my sample directory tree at the top of this page, thus pre-testing it before attempting any more of these wild experiments? I've already spent too much time with trial-and-error myself, that's why I asked here. Sorry.

Comment: @syntaxerror once more. checked on your files

Comment: YES, this one works fine! Thank you for your efforts and time. (Even though "Wiki-Greg" would tear out his hair when he saw this. I mean, both my _and_ your script. I know that he is a profound hater of the "`eval` trickery". :))

Comment: Upvote - OK done, but I don't want to put the check-mark on it yet because it might give the impression that the question might be in a sort of "closed" state. Several approaches are usually a better way of learning new things and ways, though.

Comment: Well, if you need only the list of files and you are not going to make find do any action other than -print then there is much simpler solution: `find -type f|grep -v -f file_with_patterns_not_to_show` however, the solution in my answer will not even descend into the folders that are 'blacklisted'

Comment: Serge, @syntaxerror: Note that the answer as posted wouldn't work in general, because the elements of `excl_d` are expanded three times. It works if none of the elements of `excl_d` contain whitespace or other shell special characters. I've added some missing quoting, but note that I haven't fully reviewed the long string of expansions, there might still be bugs. This isn't a good approach when arrays are available.

Comment: @Gilles I was answering a question. This doesn't implies that I like the approaches like that at all.

Comment: @Serge I was well aware of the `grep -v` pipe "solution" from the beginning, even before opening this question. However, please try to start thinking of _real huge_ directory trees, and what _significant_ differences in completion time you might eventually be encountering! This could even sum up to whole minutes of difference in the long run.

Comment: @syntaxerror Yes, and this is why I did not proposed you that from the very beginning and pointed you the `-prune` option: if you do the thing like you presented in your Q then you have some reasons to do so. I do not make any assumptions on someone's experience. The figures (I mean reputation, e.t.c.) are meaningless in a sense